# Replace value within a comma-delimited string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, substring

Suppose I have the following comma-delimited column value in MySQL: `foo,bar,baz,bar,foo2`

What is the best way to replace whatever is in the 4th position (in this case `bar`) of this string with `barAAA` (so that we change `foo,bar,baz,bar,foo2` to `foo,bar,baz,barAAA,foo2`)? Note that `bar` occurs both in position 2 as well as position 4.

I know that I can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in MySQL to get the value of whatever is in position 4, but have not been able to figure out how to replace the value in position 4 with a new value.

I need to do this without creating a UDF or stored function, via using only the standard string functions in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql select where field in csv string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265463/mysql-select-where-field-in-csv-string)

Comment: Gross. This is why God invented programming languages.

Comment: Relational databases and comma-delimited values don't really mix. Is it possible to alter your schema to be properly normalized?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... maybe this?

```
SELECT @before := CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`columnname`,',',3),','),
       @len := LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`columnname`,',',4)+1
FROM `tablename` WHERE ...;

SELECT CONCAT(@before,'newstring',SUBSTRING(`columnname`,@len+1)) AS `result`
FROM `tablename` WHERE ...;
```

Replace things as needed, but that should just about do it.

**EDIT**: Merged into one query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(`columnname`,',',3),
        ',newstring,',
        SUBSTRING(`columnname`, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`columnname`,',',4)+1))
    ) as `result`
FROM `tablename` WHERE ...;
```

That `+1` may need to be `+2`, I'm not sure, but that should work.

Comment: Is it possible to do it using a single SELECT statement and without using variables?

Comment: As it happens, yes, since each variable is only used once. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You first split your problem in two parts:

1. locate the comma and split the string in values separated by comma.
2. update the table with same string and some substring appended.

For the first part I would suggest you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)

And for the second part you should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

One more thing there is no shortcut to any problem. You should not run from the problem. Take it as a challenge. Learn while you search for the answer. Best thing take guidance from here and Try to do more researching and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   UPDATE yourtable
   SET
      categories =
       TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(CONCAT(',',REPLACE(col, ',', ',,'), ','),',2,', ''), ',,', ',')
       )
   WHERE
     FIND_IN_SET('2', categories)
```

taken from here [The best way to remove value from SET field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14643152/5863441)