# Associative Array as User variable in MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, associative-array

Is it possible to define **associative array** as user variables inside a MySQL Function?
If it is possible, how can i create a array like:

```
nep_years[2002]=[31,31,32,32,31,30,30,29,30,29,30,30];
```

inside a MySQL Function?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Curious how you plan on using this. Are you expecting to simply pass a function the value of "2002", and get a list of comma-delimited results?

Comment: @Choosun: I was thinking of passing the key `2002` and the index of the values like 0,1,2 and then return the value form that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Array's in Mysql but you could use temporary tables and function to acheave something similar.

Not sure if thats what you want.

```
#Delete temp table and functions
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nep_years_vals;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `nep_func`;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `nep_func2`;

#create new temp table for 'array'
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nep_years_vals(nep_key INT, nep_val INT);
#Insert array values
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '31');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '31');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '32');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '32');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '31');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '30');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '30');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '29');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '30');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '29');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '30');
INSERT INTO nep_years_vals(nep_key, nep_val) VALUES ('2002', '30');
#Declare function for selecting array element
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `nep_func`(`nep_key_search` INT, `nep_element_num` INT)
    RETURNS INT
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE myid INT UNSIGNED;
        select nep_val INTO myid from nep_years_vals WHERE nep_key = nep_key_search LIMIT nep_element_num, 1;
    RETURN myid;
END;
$$
#Declare function for getting multiple elements from one array
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `nep_func2`(`nep_key_search` INT, `nep_elements` TEXT)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
     DECLARE inipos INTEGER;
    DECLARE endpos INTEGER;
    DECLARE maxlen INTEGER;
    DECLARE item VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE delim VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE allitems TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE temp INTEGER;
    DECLARE temp2 INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;

    SET delim = ',';
    SET inipos = 1;
    SET nep_elements = CONCAT(nep_elements, delim);
    SET maxlen = LENGTH(nep_elements);

    REPEAT
        SET endpos = LOCATE(delim, nep_elements, inipos);
        SET item =  SUBSTR(nep_elements, inipos, endpos - inipos);

        IF item <> '' AND item IS NOT NULL THEN           
            IF allitems <> '' THEN
                    SET allitems = CONCAT(allitems, ',');
                END IF;
                    SET temp2 = nep_func(nep_key_search, CONVERT(item, UNSIGNED INTEGER));
                    IF temp2 IS NULL THEN
                        SET allitems = CONCAT(allitems, 'NULL');
                    END IF;
                    IF temp2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                        SET allitems = CONCAT(allitems, temp2);
                    END IF;
                    #SET allitems = CONCAT(allitems, nep_func(nep_key_search, CONVERT(item, UNSIGNED INTEGER)));
        END IF;
        SET inipos = endpos + 1;
    UNTIL inipos >= maxlen END REPEAT;

    RETURN allitems;
END;
$$

#Examples, tested on mysql 5.5.27 WIN32
select nep_func(2002, 0);
#Result INTEGER: 31
select nep_func2(2002, '0,1,2,3,100,101');
#Result TEXT: 31,31,32,32,NULL,NULL
#If element does not exists it returns "NULL"
```

String split borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218174/1805836)

Answer (score 0):

have you attempted to exercise any of the power of group_concat()?  i have used it to create csv structures many times.

```
select group_concat(id) sold_ids where item_sold = 1;

|---------------------|
| sold_ids            |
|---------------------|
| "12,45,74,100,123"  |
|---------------------|
```

which, perhaps, you could then assign as a variable to pass around inside your function.

Comment: To achieve this i need to create a tables to store the data and then in that function i have to query the result. So i was thinking to overcome this and define a associative array inside a function, is there any alternative?