# Create a temp table in Select Query at runtime in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i am having a  table emp like

```
____________________________
ID | Name  | Address
____________________________
 1 | Jack  | Street  On Road
 2 | Jill  | Park Side Lane
```

---

**I want to create a table at SELECT runtime that will create a new table on the basis of address spilited with every space. Something Like**

---

```
ID | WORD   | EMP_ID
 1 | Street | 1
 2 | On     | 1
 3 | Road   | 1
 4 | Park   | 2
 5 | Side   | 2
 6 | Lane   | 2
```

---

Comment: split it directly, don't need a temporary table

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a user defined function as given in this post [How to split the name string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql) and use the same in your query.