# Using SQL split

Tags: c#, sql, select, split, substring

In one of my tables I am storing GroupIDs in a format of: '2#3#5' which means a user belongs to groups 2, 3 and 5. How can I amend my query to state g.GroupID IN (2,3,5) ? Where it's getting 2,3,5 FROM

```
SELECT GroupIDs FROM BW_Staff WHERE StaffCode = ''
```

// Output: 2#3#5

g.GroupID IN (2, 3, 5) 
2, 3, 5 values needs to be from this query so it needs to be splitted by hash?

```
SELECT g.Name, u.StaffCode,  SUBSTRING(u.Perms, 47, 1) AS Staff_Perm_Grant,
       SUBSTRING(g.Perms, 47, 1) AS Group_Perm_Grant 
FROM BW_Groups g,
     BW_Staff u
WHERE g.GroupID IN (2, 3, 5) and u.StaffCode = 'KAA'
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: No join condition? Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad design.

Comment: I would create another table "Groups" with UID, UserId, GroupNumber instead of a concatenated string field.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that it probably is a badly designed database (you should be creating a 'Groups' table with a many-to-many relation to the 'Staff' table), so you can join both.

It is possible to split the string in SQL Server 2016, using `string_split(<field>, <delimiter>)`.
[How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

In MySQL you have no such luck but it's possible to create a function to do the same thing: 
[How to split the name string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)