# Change position of last name and rest of name in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

My 'name' column has names stored like this

Lastname Firstname Middlename

I want to display it like this in my query:

Firstname Middlename Lastname

- Not all records have a middle name, so they may be 1 or 2 spaces in the column

I have tried this :

```
SELECT CONCAT ( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1) , ' ' , SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', -1) ) AS nicename`
```

But this only gives the last name. The "-1" part is not working...

Thanks for all help.

Comment: You will have a problem with some name composed name. Let's use someone famous `Leonardo Da Vinci` aka `Leonardo di ser Piero da Vinci`. You will end up with `Leonardo Vinci`. And this is way common than you think. Portuguese, Italian, some french firstname, ...

Comment: Just for the story, a Belgian had problem in US to register I can't remember to what official institution because her first name was `Marie Anne`. The space was not autorized but she can't be called `Marie` because this is not her name.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, that's a bad design, Now, since your middlename part may be empty, you may bear with it and just select the name saying `select name from tbl1`.

Else, consider re-designing your table to have separate columns for `Lastname`, `Firstname` and  `Middlename` and then You don't need all of this. You can just get data from all 3 columns saying

```
select concat(Firstname, Middlename, Lastname ) as nicename
from tbl1;
```

Comment: @user2298034, post some sample data for the name column.

Comment: Sample data from name column ( sorry I dont know how to format):

`
Springsteen Bruce

Dylan Bob

Wodehouse Pelham Grenville

Obama Barack Hussein
`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution :

```
 SELECT concat ( TRIM( SUBSTR(`name`, LOCATE(' ', `name`)) ), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) ) as nicename
```

Source: [How to split the name string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)