# How to split one column value into multiple column in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `emp_hist` FROM  employee
```

***ANSWER:-***

> Primary Teacher~2005-2007~RM3000~Study~Primary School Mandarin Teacher~SJKC Yoke Nam~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I need to split this value using '~' this symbol in phpmyadmin
 Can any one help me?

I tried already `split_str` it doesn't work..

Comment: Split to separate rows?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: you can use php `explode()` function to split the values by `~`. or you want to split in `mysql` ?

Comment: Check if the answers here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql