# Split a database entry separated by commas into several labels c# .NET MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a database which is saving "Address" in one cell (i.e. "123, Park Avenue, New York, USA")

I am wondering how I would display those on my front end in separate ASP Text Boxes as if they are stored separately?

So when displayed on the front end it would look like

```
123
Park Avenue
New York 
USA
```

All in separated text boxes.

My query is pulling the one entry through to the front end but I dont know how to "Split" it?

Comment: You should split that string by comma delimiter in order to get string array. After that you can bind each string individually to the desired textbox.

Comment: Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14951159/3270427