# Explode one column value into two column in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to split one column into two column and update into other two column.

Like below.

```
Name              FirstName      LastName
ABC NAME             ABC           NAME
PQR RNP              PQR           RNP
SUM NUM              SUM           NUM
```

explode and update name field value and update into same tables two column FirstName and LastName.

Comment: explode in php, create array to save into database and that's it. What's the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql might help

Comment: no php. only mysql

Comment: There is no string split function in MySQL.You'll have to create your own function. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this directly in MySQL, you would need the following queries:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN FirstName VARCHAR(30),
                      ADD COLUMN LastName VARCHAR(30);
UPDATE yourtable 
    SET FirstName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1),
        LastName = IF(LOCATE(' ', Name) = 0, '', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1));
ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP COLUMN Name;
```

Always back up your table before making structural modifications.

Comment: but what if i have single value in name like abc than as per your query it will update same name in both the field. :(

Comment: You're right - I was just going on the sample data. What do you want it to do in that scenario? make the Name the FirstName or the LastName?

Comment: I see you have posted an answer anyway but for future reference I have updated my answer to have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

```
UPDATE campaign_participants SET first_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX( name,  ' ', 1 ) ,
last_name = IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX( name,  ' ', 1 ) != SUBSTRING_INDEX( name,  ' ', -1 ), SUBSTRING_INDEX( name,  ' ', -1 ), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Name,
  LEFT(Name, LOCATE(' ', Name) - 2) AS FirstName,
  RIGHT(Name, LENGTH(Name) - LOCATE(' ', Name)) AS LastName
FROM
  my_table;
```

If you're using a different SQL engine you might want to change `LENGTH()` to `LEN()` and `LOCATE()` to `CHARINDEX()`.