# Extract data between two slashes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling to get my head around a problem I have, I'm trying to create two fields from one `Productcategories.fullpath`.

The first will take the data before the first slash, which is working well.

Below is the code I have for this:

```
LEFT(Productcategories.Fullpath, CHARINDEX('/',ProductCategories.Fullpath + '/') - 1) as shortpath,
```

The second issue I have, is I now need to also extract between the second and third slash into another column called middlepath.

I can't get this to work for love nor money, the data is made up of three units separated by /.

If anyone can help, I will be eternally grateful, as SQL I can do a little, but i'm no programmer.

Data looks like Products\lifts\small lifts (length can vary considerably).

Output should be the "Lifts" part

Comment: Tag appropriate database name. Add sample data and expected output also.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Can you use STRING_SPLIT? There are a few questions here about processing comma-separated lists in SQL so maybe you can adapt one of those.

Comment: Different database products use different dialects of SQL. string manipulation code is usually product specific. Please add the tag for the database product you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, PostgreSql etc'). A specific version tag is also recommended, since different versions have different capabilities.

Comment: you create split function ,and use many time more info :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql

Comment: Use RIGHT to get everything after your first '/', then wrap that in your LEFT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 string functions: [`left()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`right()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`charindex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like this:

```
select
  left(Fullpath, charindex('\', Fullpath) - 1) shortpath,
  left(
    right(Fullpath, len(Fullpath) - charindex('\', Fullpath)),
    charindex('\', right(Fullpath, len(Fullpath) - charindex('\', Fullpath))) - 1
  ) middle
from Productcategories
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=490d44a314d450f9c93c0179158c61a8).
Result:

```
> shortpath | middle
> :-------- | :-----
> Products  | lifts
```

For the case that there is only 1 "\" or none it's more complicated:

```
select
  case charindex('\', Fullpath)
     when 0 then Fullpath
     when 1 then ''
     else left(Fullpath, charindex('\', Fullpath) - 1)                            
  end shortpath,                                
  case charindex('\', Fullpath)
     when 0 then ''
     else case charindex('\', Fullpath, charindex('\', Fullpath) + 1)
       when 0 then substring(Fullpath, charindex('\', Fullpath) + 1, len(Fullpath))
       else left(
         right(Fullpath, len(Fullpath) - charindex('\', Fullpath)),
         charindex('\', right(Fullpath, len(Fullpath) - charindex('\', Fullpath))) - 1
       )         
     end            
  end middle                                
from Productcategories
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e404/11).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I seem to be getting "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function when i run with this. can you advise at all? thank you

Comment: Is there a case that in the string there is only 1 "\" ? Or none?

Comment: Im really sorry but i dont follow, if referring to blank space, there can be many

Comment: Ah ok i see now, there will always be at least 2

Comment: If there are at least 2 you can see from the demo that this code is working. Is there a case that instead of "\" there is "//", or that there are 2 consecutive "\\"?

Comment: Sorry, just double checked the database, there are fields with 1 and some with none, they are never consecutive

Comment: Thank you so much for this, i must be doing something wrong though, as Shortpath now mirrors fullpath, and middle has nothing in it at all. I will double check all i have here.  thank you again

Comment: *Shortpath now mirrors fullpath, and middle has nothing in it at all* Check the 2nd demo. When there is no "\" then Shortpath = fullpath and middle = ''.

Comment: I agree, the demo works fine, im checking the rest of the query my end to see whats affecting it. thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the Output as lifts.

```
declare @t table (Files varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('Products\lifts\small')

select substring(files,CHARINDEX('\',files)+1,CHARINDEX('\', files, (CHARINDEX('\', files)+1)) - CHARINDEX('\',files)-1) from @t
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, should i be using it like this

Comment: declare @t table (Files varchar(50))

insert into @t values (productcategories.fullpath)

select replace(substring(files,CHARINDEX('\',files)+1,len(files)),'\','') from @t