# Converting Degrees/Minutes/Seconds to Decimals using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using MySQL version: 5.7.22

I've got two columns Latitude and Longitude both in Degrees/Minutes/Seconds format that I want to convert to Decimal format ex: `48° 52.250' N` to `48.93611111`

I have the following script but I'm stuck at how to split the degrees minutes and seconds. I cannot hard-code the values as I've done here `left(Latitude,2)` since the degrees might have 3 decimals as well

```
SELECT Latitude,
       left(Latitude, 2) +
       (TRUNCATE((Latitude - TRUNCATE(Latitude)) * 100) / 60) +
       (((Latitude * 100) - TRUNCATE(Latitude * 100)) * 100) / (60 * 60) AS DECIMAL_DEGREES
  FROM small_ocean_data
```

The formula for the conversion is this: `D + M/60 + S/3600 * -1 if direction in ['W', 'S'] else 1`

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: I would rethink the design of the table, storing in 3 fields Degrees, Minutes and Seconds. That would make everything easier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two) and [How to split the name string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I use this formula of yours: D + M/60 + S/3600
Where I believe D is Degrees and M are Minutes and S are Seconds.
With this select:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('48° 52.250', '°',1) + 
       (SUBSTRING_INDEX('48° 52.250',' ',1)/60) +  
       (SUBSTRING_INDEX('48° 52.250','.',1)/3600);
```

Or for your database:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(Latitude, '°', 1) + 
       (SUBSTRING_INDEX(Latitude ,' ',1)/60) +  
       (SUBSTRING_INDEX(Latitude ,'.',1)/3600) "DECIMAL_DEGREES"
FROM small_ocean_data;
```

I get **48.81333333333333**

48 + 0.8 + 0.013333333333333334

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=783fd40a886c240b5abb761cdfeaba10)

Comment: This is what I was looking for @VBoka Thanks a ton! I've suggested one small edit, please have a look and update accordingly

Comment: You are welcome @Akash, I have updated as suggested with little change: it is `, 2` in first SUBSTRING_INDEX and not `, 1`. I have also updated the DEMO.

Comment: There's one more catch about the direction, `-1 if direction in ['W', 'S'] else 1`. How do you think we can include this in the query.

Comment: You add 1 to the final result  if it is not direction in ['W', 'S'] and subsract 1 if it is ?

Comment: Multiply by -1 if ['W', 'S']

Comment: Also now that you are using SUBSTRING_INDEX to find the degree, it should be `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Latitude, '°', 1)` instead of 2

Comment: check this demo  for direction https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=17bd8b412574037a3694a11603251cef

Comment: Yes, in every place it should be 1. I have corrected it.

Comment: ```select (SUBSTRING_INDEX("48° 52.250' N",'°', 1) + (SUBSTRING_INDEX("48° 52.250' N",' ',2)/60) +  (SUBSTRING_INDEX("48° 52.250' N",'.',3)/3600))  * CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX("48° 52.250' W", "' ", -1) in ('W', 'S') THEN (-1)
    ELSE 1
END
 "DECIMAL_DEGREES";
```
This works for me!

Comment: I found out that the entire number with `'` is actually minutes. Seconds is denoted by `''`. This is my final query:  ```ALTER TABLE small_ocean_data ADD
Lat_in_degree TEXT; 
Long_in_degree TEXT;

SET small_ocean_data.Lat_in_degree = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(small_ocean_data.Latitude,'°', 1) + ((SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(small_ocean_data.Latitude,"'",1), "°", -1)) + 0.0) /60) *
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(small_ocean_data.Latitude, "' ", -1) in ('W', 'S') THEN (-1) ELSE 1 END
select * from small_ocean_data;``` 

@VBoka can you please update answer accordingly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Akash well the comment you made is just fine because the question is not about that. My answer is ok for the question and if I update the answer it will be confusing. Also, the main thing is the logic of the solution: use of SUBSTRING_INDEX. Cheers and thanks for the additional info.