# Replace the special characters

Tags: mysql, sql

```
data = "Qwsdyz_qwrbc_bcD_qwEr"
```

What I need is:

1. remove all the `_`
2. all characters to be in lower
3. the starting letter should be caps for all the 4 like this `(QwsdyzQwrbcBcdQwer)`
4. whatever changes made in above statement should't change the result like if we changed like `Qwsdqwqyz_qwrwqeqwebc_bcqwD_qqwwEr_dadakjas` i need the result like `QesdqwqyzQwrwqeqwebcBcqwdQqwwerDasakjas`

Please help me with MySQL coding.

```
set @data="Qwsdyz_qwrbc_bcD_qwEr";
select lower(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data,"_",1)) into @data1;
select ucase(left(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data,"_",2),1)) into @data2;
select lower(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data,"_",2)) into @data3;
select substring(reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX(reverse(@data3),"_",1)),2) into @data4; 
select reverse((lower(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data,"_",3)))) into @data5;
select (reverse(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data5,"_",1))) into @data6;
select ucase(left(@data6,1)) into @data7;
select substring(@data6,2) into @data8;
select reverse(@data) into @data9;
select reverse(lower(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data9,"_",1))) into @data10;
select ucase(left(@data10,1)) into @data11;
select substring(@data10,2) into @data12;
select concat(@data1,@data2,@data4,@data7,@data8,@data11,@data12) data;
```

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have already tried.

Comment: Am new to this site please tell me how to place the code..

Comment: If you are new, you might want to read the "how to post a question" Also i kinda miss what you tried yourself.

Comment: Thank you fro the advice @Dorvalla

Answer (score 0):

You can use split functions replied in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql). Do sub-string and find every splited strings first character with **UPPER()** function do it upper character and **LOWER()** function do other characters to lowercase. And finally join with **CONCAT()** function.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a messy `concat()` and `substring_index()`:

```
select concat(concat(upper(left(lower(substring_index(data, '_', 1)), 1)),
                     lower(substr(lower(substring_index(data, '_', 1)), 2))
                    ),
              concat(upper(left(lower(substring_index(substring_index(data, '_', 2), '_', -1)), 1)),
                     lower(substr(lower(substring_index(substring_index(data, '_', 2), '_', -1)), 2))
                    ),
              concat(upper(left(lower(substring_index(substring_index(data, '_', 3), '_', -1)), 1)),
                     lower(substr(lower(substring_index(substring_index(data, '_', 3), '_', -1)), 2))
                    ),
              concat(upper(left(lower(substring_index(substring_index(data, '_', 4), '_', -1)), 1)),
                     lower(substr(lower(substring_index(substring_index(data, '_', 4), '_', -1)), 2))
                    )
             )
from (select 'Qwsdyz_qwrbc_bcD_qwEr' as data) x
```

SQL is not optimized for string manipulations.  I would advise you to do this in another tool, such as Python, if that is possible.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4eb2105fb51fa43031b2cda5fd35e73) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank You i will try it out!   there is no change happening its show the data as it is.

Comment: @Manickam . . . The code works.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I need answer like this "qwsdyzQwrbcBcdQwr"

Comment: @Manickam . . . You don't need the `concat_ws()` then.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you ! but if i change any character or add will it affect the query

Comment: @Manickam . . . This will work for any string with three underscores that you apply it to.

Comment: thank you bro..! can you rewrite the same as i can add or change with no restriction