# SQL - How can I sum elements of an array?

Tags: sql, csv, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using SQL with pyspark and hive, and I'm new to all of it.
I have a hive table with a column of type string, like this:

```
id | values
1  | '2;4;4'
2  |  '5;1'
3  |  '8;0;4'
```

I want to create a query to obtain this:

```
id | values | sum
1  | '2.2;4;4'  | 10.2
2  |  '5;1.2' |  6.2
3  |  '8;0;4' | 12
```

By using split(values, ';') I can get arrays like ['2.2','4','4'], but I still need to convert them into decimal numbers and sum them.
Is there a not too complicated way to do this?

Thank you so so much in advance! And happy coding to you all :)

Comment: Multi-valued columns are almost always an indication of a poor database design. Normalizing tables with such columns to first normal form is almost always the way to go.

Comment: Which version of spark are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark solution

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col,split
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType 
#UDF to sum the split values returning none when non numeric values exist in the string
#Change the implementation of the function as needed
def values_sum(split_list):
    total = 0
    for num in split_list:
        try:
            total += float(num)
        except ValueError:
            return None
    return total

values_summed = udf(values_sum,FloatType())
res = df.withColumn('summed',values_summed(split(col('values'),';')))
res.show()
```

The solution could've been a one-liner if it were known the array values are of a given data type. However, it is better to go with a safer implementation that covers all cases.

Hive solution

Use `explode` with `split` and `group by` to sum the values.

```
select id,sum(cast(split_value as float)) as summed
from tbl
lateral view explode(split(values,';')) t as split_value
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

From **`Spark-2.4+`**

We don't have to use `explode` on arrays but directly work on array's using [higher order functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/16/introducing-new-built-in-functions-and-higher-order-functions-for-complex-data-types-in-apache-spark.html).

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df=spark.createDataFrame([("1","2;4;4"),("2","5;1"),("3","8;0;4")],["id","values"])

#split and creating array<int> column
df1=df.withColumn("arr",split(col("values"),";").cast("array<int>"))

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

spark.sql("select *,aggregate(arr,0,(x,y) -> x + y) as sum from tmp").drop("arr").show()
#+---+------+---+
#| id|values|sum|
#+---+------+---+
#|  1| 2;4;4| 10|
#|  2|   5;1|  6|
#|  3| 8;0;4| 12|
#+---+------+---+

#in dataframe API

df1.selectExpr("*","aggregate(arr,0,(x,y) -> x + y) as sum").drop("arr").show()
#+---+------+---+
#| id|values|sum|
#+---+------+---+
#|  1| 2;4;4| 10|
#|  2|   5;1|  6|
#|  3| 8;0;4| 12|
#+---+------+---+
```

Answer (score -1):

write a [stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql) which does the job:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_AND_SUM ( s VARCHAR(1024) ) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   ...
END
```