# Tricky SQL for separating a string from one cell into two cells

Tags: mysql, sql

currently I have a tricky problem to solve, which I had previously realised in VBScript and I am now trying to transfer to a **MySQL** view. So far I have not succeeded in doing this. Who has a solution for the following task?

Table1

```
   Num Code                 Key CodeCommon CodeIndiv
     1 FE/MCG/90/K            1 FE/MCG      /90/K
     2 FE/MCG/150/5           1 FE/MCG      /150/5
     3 FE/MCG/200/26          1 FE/MCG      /200/26
     4 FE/MCGO67/340/15       1 FE/MCG      O67/340/15
     5 FE/MCG/600/315         1 FE/MCG      /600/315
     6 FE/MCG/345/17          1 FE/MCG      /345/17
     7 FE/MCGH1/90/K          1 FE/MCG      H1/90/K
     8 HE/MCGI3/150/5         1 FE/MCG      I3/150/5
     9 FE/MCGJ2/200/26        1 FE/MCG      J2/200/26
    10 FE/MCGK88/340/15       1 FE/MCG      K88/340/15
    11 FE/MCGL543/600/315     1 FE/MCG      L543/600/315
    12 FE/MCGM4653/345/17     1 FE/MCG      M4653/345/17
    13 AFFJ/MCG/90/K          2    
    14 AFFJ/MCG-150/5         2    
    15 AFFJ/MCG-200/26        2    
    16 AFFJ/MCGO67-340/15     2    
    17 AFFJ/MCG/600/315       2    
    18 AFFJ/MCG/345/17        2    
    19 AFFJ/MCGH1/90/K        2    
    20 AFFJ/MCGI3/150/5       2    
    21 AFFJ/MCGJ2/200/26      2    
    22 AFFJ/MCGK88/340/15     2    
    23 AFFJ/MCGL543/600/315   2    
    24 AFFJ/MCGM4653/345/17   2
```

From this table, in the [Code] column within a [Key], determine which first characters in all cells have common values and split the result into two cells [CodeCommon] and [CodeIndiv]. The number and type of common values are completely different (numbers, letters, characters).

I would be very happy and grateful if someone could help me.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: What task?  What is the question?

Comment: `8 HE/MCGI3/150/5         1 FE/MCG      I3/150/5` eh?

Comment: What you're asking is essentially what geneticists have to do all day long, so I'd go ask them. They may well tell you that an RDBMS is not best suited to this kind of analysis.

Comment: This looks like an iterative / recursive process, probably not the best use of a RDBMS!

Comment: Why do 14, 15, 16 have hyphen instead of slash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split the name string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)

Comment: @Strawberry:
Thank you very much for the first answer and for the table format. 
Yes, I know that this query is recursive and should be in external programs rather than in the database. But in this case, it is a limited number of "order codes" to be split per item group.
I look forward to more answers.

Comment: Well, in this instance, the commonality is a simple string : 'MCG', so you can just split on that.

Comment: @Strawberry: No, that would be too simple: here is only an example; within a key, the cell code contains a wide variety of values

Comment: That's the best we can do with the sample data provided