# MySQL-extract IDs from column and search for matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

table 1 has two columns: `ID` and `details`. in the details column there is a string in this format:

```
ID1:code1,ID2:code2,...
for example:
ABC:110,ERTL:780,POV:555
```

now I need to extract the IDs mentioned in `details` column and search the table for rows with matching IDs:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (<the IDs mentioned in the details column of first row>)
```

how to run such query in MySQL 8?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'first row'? First ordered by what criterion?

Comment: Also worth noting - if you're in control of this database schema (I assume you're not, but you might be) it would make way more sense to just normalize your data rather than use a non-standard string format to store key-value pairs.

Comment: @NickBailey by first row I mean "ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"

Comment: So you can do this in pure MySQL, but it will be ugly and awful and require you do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql. If at all possible I recommend you query the database, do the string manipulation in another language and then query with a simple IN query.

Comment: I tried this `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT concat("('",REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(details, ":[0-9]+", ""),",","','"),"')") FROM table1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)`, but it returns empty result. is it wrong?

Comment: Convert your value to JSON object (2 REPLACE and CONCAT) then parse to separate values (JSON_KEYS, JSON_TABLE).